# outline in latex beamer

Tags: table-of-contents

How to add the outline of LaTeX beamer on the left side of each page? I tried:

```latex
\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

and I added `[pausesections]`. Now I want to show the contents on the right side of each page so the presentation will be easy to follow by the audiences.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Probably you are interested in something like `\useoutertheme[left]{sidebar}`. However, it is quite hard to tell if this will give you the desried result based only on your very brief description and the lack of a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing which beamer theme you currently use.

Comment: Example of MWE: `\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\begin{document}
\section{xxxxxx}
\section{yyyyy}
\subsection{zzzzz}
\begin{frame}{foo}foo\end{frame}
\end{document}`